JDBCIO.write ignoring batch size and inserting single record
I'm using Java Dataflow to insert huge data to Cloud SQL. What is observed in performance tests is Apache beam is not inserting records in a batch. Instead one insert query is triggered for each row.
Giving the same code below. If the table has composite primary key or an auto increment id column, would that cause this behavior?
exceptions.apply("Write to CloudSQL", JdbcIO.<Exception>write()
    .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration
            .create(dbDriver, dbURL)
            .withUsername(dbUSer)
            .withPassword(dbPassword))
    .withStatement(SqlConstants.INSERT_QUERY)
    .withBatchSize(1000)
    .withPreparedStatementSetter((JdbcIO.PreparedStatementSetter<Exception>) (exp, query) -> {
                try {
                    querySetValues(exp, query );
                } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
                    throw new DataflowHelper.DataflowServiceException("Error while writing to CloudSQL", e);
                }
            }
    )
);


Hi , you can check that PreparedStatementSetter in your code that it's correctly  setting values for multiple rows and   For Cloud SQL, the JDBC URL format should be jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database  . you can troubleshoot in that way once .

You can check that PreparedStatementSetter in your code that it's correctly setting values for multiple rows and For Cloud SQL, the JDBC URL format should be jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database. you can troubleshoot in that way once . For detailed investigation you can open a public issue tracker describing your issue  and vote [+1] and Eng team will look on the Bug .
